# Code VBA to excel read space used and free

Tags: excel, vba

I have VBA code that should read the free and used space of a drive or folder that I type into cell A1.

The free and used space should appear in cells on row 2.

```
Sub DriveSizes()

    Dim Drv As Drive
    Dim fs As New FileSystemObject
    Dim Letter As String
    Dim Total As Variant
    Dim Free As Variant
    Dim FreePercent As Variant
    Dim TotalPercent As Variant
    Dim i As Integer

    On Error Resume Next
    i = 2
    For Each Drv In fs.drives
        If Drv.IsReady Then
            Letter = Drv.DriveLetter
            Total = Drv.TotalSize
            Free = Drv.FreeSpace
            FreePercent = Free / Total
            TotalPercent = 1 - FreePercent
            Cells(i, 1).Value = Letter
            Cells(i, 2).Value = FreePercent
            Cells(i, 3).Value = TotalPercent
            Cells(i, 4).Value = Free
            Cells(i, 5).Value = Total
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Stack overflow helps you clarify what is wrong with your way of thinking about a problem. Proclaiming that you need vba code to do x feature will not get you far here.

Comment: I have a code, but I can not see what's wrong. can you help me?

Comment: <code>
SubDriveSizes()
DimDrvAsDrive
DimfsAsNewFileSystemObject
DimLetterAsString
DimTotalAsVariant
DimFreeAsVariant
DimFreePercentAsVariant
DimTotalPercentAsVariant
DimiAsInteger

OnErrorResumeNext
i=2
ForEachDrvInfs.drives
IfDrv.IsReadyThen
Letter=Drv.DriveLetter
Total=Drv.TotalSize
Free=Drv.FreeSpace

FreePercent=Free/Total
TotalPercent=1-FreePercent

Cells(i,1).Value=Letter
Cells(i,2).Value=FreePercent
Cells(i,3).Value=TotalPercent
Cells(i,4).Value=Free
Cells(i,5).Value=Total
i=i+1
EndIf
Next
EndSub
<code>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will almost work - you need to set a reference to 'Microsoft Scripting Runtime' in the VBA Editor.
Click *Tools ~ References...* and tick 'Microsoft Scripting Runtime' box.

Your code will list the size of all drives in bytes, but not any folders.

The code below **doesn't** need you to set a reference, and you should enter the folder path into cell A1 on Sheet1.  It also won't list any individual subfolders within the main folder.

```
Sub DriveSizes()

    Dim Drv As Object
    Dim Fld As Object
    Dim fs As Object
    Dim DrvPath As String

    Dim Letter As String
    Dim Total As Double
    Dim Free As Double
    Dim FreePercent As Double
    Dim TotalPercent As Double
    Dim i As Integer

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Update sheet name to suit.

        DrvPath = .Cells(1, 1)
        Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        Set Drv = fs.GetDrive(fs.GetDriveName(DrvPath))
        Set Fld = fs.GetFolder(DrvPath)

        If Drv.IsReady Then
            Letter = Drv.DriveLetter
            Total = Drv.TotalSize
            Free = Drv.FreeSpace
            FreePercent = Free / Total
            TotalPercent = 1 - FreePercent
            .Cells(2, 1).Value = Letter
            .Cells(2, 2).Value = "Free Percent: " & Format(FreePercent, "0.00%")
            .Cells(2, 3).Value = "Remaining Percent: " & Format(TotalPercent, "0.00%")
            .Cells(2, 4).Value = "Free Space: " & FormatNumber(Free / 1024, 0)
            .Cells(2, 5).Value = "Total Size: " & FormatNumber(Total / 1024, 0)

            .Cells(3, 1).Value = Fld.Name
            .Cells(3, 5).Value = "Size: " & FormatNumber(Fld.Size, 0) & " bytes."
        End If

    End With

    On Error GoTo 0

Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    Select Case Err.Number
        Case 76 'Path not found.
            MsgBox "That file path does not exist." & vbCr & _
                   "Please check the folder exists and you have entered the correct path.", vbCritical + vbOKOnly
            Err.Clear
        Case Else
            MsgBox Err.Number & vbCr & Err.Description, vbCritical + vbOKOnly
            Err.Clear
    End Select

End Sub
```